# Where can I find the old "Developer Collaboration" plugin?

Tags: java, netbeans, collaboration, pair-programming

Once upon a time there is netbeans plugin called "Developer Collaboration" which allows you make remote pair programming.

Now, in Netbeans 6.7, there is no more this "Developer Collaboration" but there something called "Kenai support". Unfortunately Kenai does not seems to have a real time editor and it seems to be usable only for opensource project, but my project is closed source.

I switched back to the Netbeans 6.5 but I discovered that the "Developer Collaboration" plugin is no more available for download through the Plugin Manager (from Tools > Plugins) and I'm not able to find it from the [plugin portal](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/)

Where can I find the old "Developer Collaboration" plugin? Or which alternative I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tryed on 6.9 and it doesn't work. Editor Library 1.27 is required, 6.9 has 2+

Answer (score 4):

The user `msmart` posted this on the NetBeans Forums, explaining how to install the Developer Collaboration plugin on NetBeans 6.7:

> For those of you who want to connect to an XMPP server for collaboration but cannot (or do not want to) use Kennai. The old Developer Collaboration plugin still works for 6.7 but you have to download and install the NBM files manually.
>
> Here is how I got it to work:
>   1. Download the following NBM files from the Netbeans 6.5.1 repository.
>   com-sun-collablet-moxc.nbm
>   com-sun-collablet.nbm
>   org-netbeans-libs-xmlbeans.nbm
>   org-netbeans-modules-collab-channel-chat-html.nbm
>   org-netbeans-modules-collab-channel-chat-java.nbm
>   org-netbeans-modules-collab-channel-chat-text.nbm
>   org-netbeans-modules-collab-channel-chat-xml.nbm
>   org-netbeans-modules-collab-channel-chat.nbm
>   org-netbeans-modules-collab-channel-filesharing.nbm
>   org-netbeans-modules-collab-channel-output.nbm
>   org-netbeans-modules-collab-kit.nbm
>   org-netbeans-modules-collab-provider-im.nbm
>   org-netbeans-modules-collab-ui.nbm
>
> They are currently located at the
>   following URL:
>   http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/6.5.1/uc/final/stable/patch4/extra/
>
> 2. Put all these files in the same directory.
> 3. Open Netbeans 6.7.
> 4. Click Tools->Plugins
> 5. Select the "Downloaded" Tab
> 6. Click the "Add Plugins" button
> 7. Browse to the folder you saved the NBM files in.
> 8. Select all 13 files (CTRL A).
> 9. Click OK.
> 10. Click Install.
>
> Enjoy.

Comment: Note: Community wiki because this isn't my answer. I simply moved an answer from the NetBeans forums that appeared to have the answer needed for this question in the event that the relevant postings are removed from the NetBeans forums.