# Comparing local and remote files in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, ftp, synchronization, diff

Is there a way to compare local and remote (FTP) file in NetBeans?

There is an upload (and download) command in NetBeans. What I want to do is to see the changes between local and remote version in built-in compare tool when I am using download and upload and ideally select which changes to apply.

In short, I would like to sync local and remote files using NetBeans' compare tool.

Answer (score 6):

Right click + synchronise. A new window appears. Then select the "Review difference" icon.

Answer (score 1):

PHPStorm can do it. The same setup as Netbeans, with your local files which can be uploaded to the server with a click, but you can do a lovely visual diff with the remote version with one click too. If you're not working with PHP, i think they have other very similar products. Only downside is it's £80 for a license.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select a file in the main editor or in Files/Projects panel
2. Select Tools->Diff and a new window will open allowing you to select the file to "Diff to"

Available as code or text difference. Very good

Comment: You can use this, if you rename the local file, download the remote, then select both and right click on `Tools > Diff`. But thats not very comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no way to do it in NetBeans. There are however some standalone solutions, like [vuBrief](http://www.vu-brief.spb.ru/eng/) or [FtpVC](http://www.prestosoft.com/ps.asp?page=fvc_ftpvc) (not free).

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to use the old collaboration plugin or kenai support to use remote editing features.

E.g. see:
[Where can I find the old "Developer Collaboration" plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176927/where-can-i-find-the-old-developer-collaboration-plugin)